# How does String concatenation work in terms of the String Pool?

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection, concatenation, string-pool

```
13: String a = "";
14: a += 2;
15: a += 'c';
16: a += false; 
17: if ( a == "2cfalse") System.out.println("==");
18: if ( a.equals("2cfalse")) System.out.println("equals");
```

Output:
`equals`

**Please correct me if I am wrong...**

At line 13 a new `String` object is created and the reference is stored at `a`. (a = "")

At line 14 a new `String` object is created and the reference is stored in `a`. The previous `String` object becomes eligible of garbage collection(GC). (a = "2c")

At line 15 a new `String` object is created and the reference is stored in `a`. The previous `String` object becomes eligible of garbage collection(GC). (a = "2cfalse").

Now, the `String pool` consists of the `2cfalse` literal. Therefore, at line-17, *shouldn't `a == "2cfalse"` evaluate to `true` since they are both pointing to the same object in memory?*

However, the program output is just `==`. Where did I go wrong? Please can someone explain it to me...

Comment: Just use `StringBuilder` if these be a concern to you (unless this is homework and you need an explanation).

Comment: YES, I need an explanation...

Comment: You're off with the values, i.e. after line 14 the string is `"2"` and after line 15 it is `"2c"`.

Answer (score 2):

`"2cfalse"` is only added to the String pool in line 17, when you compare `a` to the literal `"2cfalse"`.

The instance referenced by `a` prior to line 17 wasn't added to the String pool, so it's not the same instance as the `"2cfalse"` literal.

If you add a call to `a.intern ()` just before line 17, the instance referenced by `a` will be added to the pool (since it wasn't already in the pool), and the condition in line 17 would evaluate to true.

If a `String` equal to `"2cfalse"` was already in the pool prior to calling `a.intern()`, you'd have to assign it back to `a` (i.e. `a = a.intern();`) in order for `a` to reference the instance stored in the pool.

```
String a = "";
a += 2;
a += 'c';
a += false; 
a.intern (); // or a = a.intern(); in case the pool already contains "2cfalse"
if ( a == "2cfalse") System.out.println("==");
if ( a.equals("2cfalse")) System.out.println("equals");
```

Output:

```
==
equals
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please explain why are the previous instances before line 17 not being added to the String Pool?

Comment: @S.Tiss not every String instance is automatically added to the pool. I believe only instances of String literals and instances for which `intern()` was called are added to the pool.

Comment: @S.Tiss only literals will be added to the string pool by the JVM, other strings may be added by calling `intern()`. Note, however, that if you _constuct_ a string like you're doing with `"2cfalse"` your `==` case would fail even if the literal was already on the string pool. That's because new string objects are not on the pool by default, even if they have the same values as those on the pool.

Comment: I'd add one additional piece of information for clarity: if `"2cfalse"` already was in the pool when `a.intern()` is called you'd need to assign the returned string or `==` would still fail. In the case above it works because the instance is put onto the pool before retrieving it via the literal.

Comment: @Thomas that's correct

Comment: *compile-time constants* are added to the pool. So, `("" + 2 + 'c' + false)  == "2cfalse"` will evaluate to `true`. Though, if you write the entire expression that way, it will get replaced by the compile time constant `true` at compile-time already, so still no string will be added to the pool at all. If you write `String s = "" + 2 + 'c' + false; boolean b = s == "2cfalse";`, `b` will be `true` and the string added to the pool but that just demonstrates that the *object identity* is more important than the pool.